# How to sync data to AWS DynamoDB using Amplify DataStore?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've setup a React Amplify project. I have successfully got Auth working using Cognito User Pools but can't seem to figure out DataStore/API.

I currently use DataStore to save data locally but it doesn't seem to update in the backend. I do have the `aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint` in the `aws-exports.js`.

Not sure how to enable the Sync Engine in [this guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/how-it-works/q/platform/js#sync-data-to-cloud).

Comment: @Kieren Crown: Did you solve your problem? I have the same issue. Build a complete app with datastore and can not deploy to amplify.

Comment: @RalfBordé I kinda got it to work with tweaks but ended up going down the route of using Apollo Client instead.

Comment: @Kieren Crown: Ok, THX, I will use API.graphql(..)  and build it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import `Amplify` from `@aws-amplify/core` and **NOT** from `aws-amplify`

The following code example worked well in App.js, at the **BOTTOM** of all your imports:

```
import Amplify from "@aws-amplify/core";
import { DataStore, Predicates } from "@aws-amplify/datastore";
import { Post, PostStatus } from "./models";

//Use next two lines only if syncing with the cloud
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

Source: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/examples/q/platform/js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataStore.query` to query the data.

`DataStore.save` to save the record etc.

Below example should be good starting point.

https://github.com/dabit3/amplify-datastore-example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly everything is set up with DataStore and working locally. The problem is that it doesn't sync to the cloud. One of the answers suggested using Apollo. You don't need Apollo. By default, and the suggested development mode of using DataStore, is local only. When you are ready to deploy to the cloud you use the command

```
amplify push
```

which provisions all of your cloud resources for the app. For more details refer to [DataStore docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/sync/q/platform/js/#push-the-backend-to-the-cloud).